# Libfreenect2 USB connection failure

Tags: libusb, openkinect, kinect-v2, libfreenect2

I have been trying to get the libfreenect2 library up and running on my Windows 10 machine and I have run into an issue that I can't get past. I have build the library and it's examples. The issues I have is when I go to run the "Protonect" example code. The output I get is listed below:

```
$ ./install/bin/Protonect.exe
Version: 0.2.0
Environment variables: LOGFILE=<protonect.log>
Usage: U:\Repositories\libfreenect2\build\install\bin\Protonect.exe [-gpu=<id>] [gl | cl | clkde | cuda | cudakde | cpu] [<device serial>]
        [-noviewer] [-norgb | -nodepth] [-help] [-version]
        [-frames <number of frames to process>]
To pause and unpause: pkill -USR1 Protonect
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] enumerating devices...
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] 8 usb devices connected
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] found valid Kinect v2 @12:2 with serial 003370163847
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] found 1 devices
Pipeline Not-Used
libusb_open returned: -99
BLAH BLAH BLAH
[Error] [Freenect2Impl] failed to open Kinect v2: @12:2 LIBUSB_ERROR_OTHER Other error
failure opening device!
```

Please ignore the "BLAH BLAH BLAH" I was using that as print statement debugging. I think I have traced the issue all the way down to this section of the core.c file libusb_open() function in libusb library:

```
r = usbi_backend->open(_dev_handle);
    if (r < 0) {
        usbi_dbg("open %d.%d returns %d", dev->bus_number, dev->device_address, r);
        libusb_unref_device(dev);
        usbi_mutex_destroy(&_dev_handle->lock);
        free(_dev_handle);
        return r;
    }
```

I couldn't find anything on the error code -99 so that is where my debugging ended. From what I understand it seems that the example code can't open the USB device to the Kinect for some reason.

I have tested the Kinect with Kinect Studio using the windows SDK and that has no problem picking up the Kinect feeds. Has anyone run into this issue before and how did you solve it? Any suggestions for what the error code means or how I might fix the USB opening issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up solving itself. Through a series of debugging attempts which you can see here:
https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/issues/812#issuecomment-288143166

I ended up reinstalling usbdk 1.0.17 and magically everything worked again. Apparently there are some issues with with usbdk 1.0.17 which require it to be reinstalled to fix some of the issues. Idk why, but if anyone comes across this issue in the future, this way my fix.